# Get all listeners from javax.swing.text.Document instances

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcomponent

I have a JTextField instance with DocumentListener registered. I'd like to remove the documentListener using this method :

```
jTextField.getDocument().removeDocumentListener(arg0)
```

The issue I am running into, is that I can't access the document listener, as the Document class doesn't offer a *getListeners()* Method.

How can I get all listeners registered into a javax.swing.text.Document object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what Document is inside you can cast the result to something that has a getListeners() method.

e.g.

```java
Document doc = jTextField.getDocument();
if (doc instanceof AbstractDocument) {
    DocumentListener[] listeners = ((AbstractDocument) doc).getDocumentListeners();
    // find listener in array and remove
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've checked, and apparently it's an AutoCompleteDocument class ( unfortunately there is no getDocumentListeners() associated with it ), Is there a way to get registered listeners for an AutoCompleteDocument instance ?

Comment: @TheByeByeMan `apparently it's an AutoCompleteDocument` - does it extend AbstractDocument? If so, then the method is already implemented in the AbstractDocument. If not, then there is no way to get the listeners unless you modify the class.

Comment: Thank you @camickr